# More than one local notification with iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6, uilocalnotification

I have about 60 local notifications in different switches but when I try it and apply more than one switch, it runs only for the last one.

Here's my code:

```
   -(IBAction)theSwitch:(id)sender{

        NSUserDefaults *defaultsB = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   if (switcher.on == 1) {

        NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  | NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

        [dateComponent setWeekday:1]; // For sunday
        [dateComponent setHour:16];
        [dateComponent setMinute:30];

        NSDate *fireDate = [gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent];

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
        [notification setAlertBody:textClass1.text];
        [notification setFireDate:fireDate];
        notification.soundName = @"bells.mp3";
        notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
        [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];


          [defaultsB setObject:@"ON" forKey:@"SwitchState"];
    }
    else  {         UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];

          [defaultsB setObject:@"OFF" forKey:@"SwitchStateOFF"];

    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you explain what is desired behavior, and currently how it is working? And by the way for Sunday you need to set Weekday==1 not 3. check this correction [dateComponent setWeekday:1]; // For sunday

Comment: Hi ... My object is schedule for student .. If users have a class he Will receive an alert for his class .... My issue is for example .. User inter in class 1 math and the switch 1 on ... And in class 2 Physics and switch 2 on , then he will receive only the last alert for class 2 .

Comment: The way you use `cancelAllLocalNotifications` might be a problem. My guess is that disabling any one switch will cancel not only the switched but also all other notifications.